# Ordering query result by numeric strings in django (postgres backend)

Tags: python, django, postgresql, orm

I have a table with a name (varchar) field that only holds numeric string and I want to order my queries by this field. But name fields are being ordered by alphabetically but I want them to be ordered numerically. 
For instance if I get 1 2 200 100 as name fields values, It is being ordered like 1 100 2 200
but I need them to be 1 2 100 200.

I could be able to come up with following row query

```
select *
from my_table as t
where t.foo='bar'
order by cast(t.name as integer);
```

But cannot represent this as django orm querysets? is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd ask first of all why you have a varchar column that needs to be treated as numeric, but never mind.

You can use the `extra` queryset method to convert your string:

```
MyTable.objects.extra(select={'int_name': 'CAST(t.name AS INTEGER)'},
                      order_by=['int_name'])
```

Comment: What would happen if one or more values in the column were no valid integers, would it resort to alphabetical, apply no order or fail?

Comment: It would fail on PostgreSQL and be fine on MySQL... I just found out after transitioning from db... If anyone know how to circumvent that, that would be great!

Comment: Interested in a solution for this, we have a column that has both text and integers. When sorted '10' sits next to '1' instead of below '9'.