# Django Ordering by Descending Order is glitched

Tags: python, django

So I have made a leaderboard in Django. It does most stuff Great except something it's drunk.

[image]

That's not normal! 70 Is higher than 540 and 200! It should be in 3rd Place not 1st! Why is that happening and how can I fix it.

I'm ordering the leaderboard using the Total or `totalpoints` in Descending order using this: `participants = Participant.objects.order_by('-totalpoints')`

This didn't happen when 70 was missing. Now when it's there it glitches. Also the Total points is added from all the challenges and if there was a problem eithher an ASCII or something else it would have crashed.

Any Help is going to be appreciated thank you!

EDIT: Replaced the last field as an IntegerField and now it's in Ascending Order...

EDIT EDIT: When the challenge 1,2,3,4 are combined they are in CharFields later converted to integers. So it was an Integer put into a field. Except when the totalpoints is now replaced with an IntegerField the leaderboard is ordering the emptry ones first.

Comment: Are you sure totalpoints are integers? The ordering would be correct if "70", "540" and "200" are strings, which are sorted lexicographically. If that's not the case, you have to show us your code. [mcve]

Comment: I changed the question a little check it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't shown any code, so it's hard to say for sure, but this looks like a case of sorting numeric strings. Your totalpoints data isn't numbers, it's strings.

If you sort a list of strings which happen to look like numbers, they don't sort like numbers.  The first digit is the most significant, and will determine the sort order:

```
>>> sorted(['200', '70', '540'], reverse=True)
['70', '540', '200']
```

If you sort them as numbers, they work correctly:

```
>>> sorted([200, 70, 540], reverse=True)
[70, 200, 540]
```

Comment: Good eye! You could add to this answer that, if this is the case, OP should either make the field an `IntegerField` or use this trick: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8941962/ordering-query-result-by-numeric-strings-in-django-postgres-backend

Answer (score 1):

You must be storing your `totalpoints` as a string instead of an integer. This will mean you're seeing the numbers ordered "alphabetically" (in reverse, because of the `-`).

If you store the `totalpoints` field in an `IntegerField`, you should have a better result.